# Login/logoff and alert sounds are not working?

Tags: sound, login-screen

I tried to chage the sound theme using Dconf but on every restart the value is reset  back to freedesktop!?!

What should I do ? How I can save the setting ?!! I can enable login sound using dconf though shutdown sound is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command should do the trick for you

> sudo cp /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/* /usr/share/sounds/

You may have to reboot your system.  Let me know if this gets you up and running.

Comment: Logoff sound still not working.